# How to plot a list of Shapely points

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, point, shapely

I created a list of Shapely `Point` objects based on the point data set. How can I plot this list of points below?

```
points = [Point(-4.85624511894443, 37.1837967179202), 
          Point(-4.855703975302475, 37.18401757756585),
          Point(-4.85516283166052, 37.1842384372115),
          Point(-4.85343407576431, 37.182006629169),
          Point(-4.85347524651836, 37.1804461589773),
          Point(-4.855792124429867, 37.18108913443582),
          Point(-4.85624511894443, 37.1837967179202)]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get two lists of `x` and `y` coordinates by accessing `x` and `y` attributes of [`Point`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#Point) and then use, for example, [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) or [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) functions of Matplotlib as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point

points = [Point(-4.85624511894443, 37.1837967179202), 
          Point(-4.855703975302475, 37.18401757756585),
          Point(-4.85516283166052, 37.1842384372115),
          Point(-4.85343407576431, 37.182006629169),
          Point(-4.85347524651836, 37.1804461589773),
          Point(-4.855792124429867, 37.18108913443582),
          Point(-4.85624511894443, 37.1837967179202)]
xs = [point.x for point in points]
ys = [point.y for point in points]
plt.scatter(xs, ys)
# or plt.plot(xs, ys) if you want to connect points by lines
```

[image]

---

If you are using Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab, you could wrap the list of points in a [`MultiPoint`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#MultiPoint) object to get an SVG image. This can be useful for debugging purposes when you want to plot something quickly without importing Matpotlib.

```
>>> MultiPoint(points)
```

gives:
[image]

Comment: What method is called that results in the graphics being displayed?  For example, if I wanted to loop over a list of Multipoint's, how can I display each?

Comment: May I suggest `xs, ys = zip(*[(point.x, point.y) for point in points])` which avoids double looping.  Or `xs, ys = zip(*[point.xy for point in points])`.  Or with numpy `xs, ys = np.c_[[np.r_[point.xy] for point in points]].T`

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use Geopandas and build a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html).

from the tutorial:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
d = {'col1': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7'], 'geometry': [Point(-4.85624511894443, 37.1837967179202), 
      Point(-4.855703975302475, 37.18401757756585),
      Point(-4.85516283166052, 37.1842384372115),
      Point(-4.85343407576431, 37.182006629169),
      Point(-4.85347524651836, 37.1804461589773),
      Point(-4.855792124429867, 37.18108913443582),
      Point(-4.85624511894443, 37.1837967179202)]}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")(choose your own crs)
```

and then just plot it:

```
gdf.plot()
```